# How to install mysql and other software to ubuntu12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 to my laptop. This is the first time I'm using this OS. Their is no software to watch videos and flash player to watch in web. I'm not being able to install also. I want mysql to install. I tried sudo apt-get install mysql-server and many similar codes available in net, but nothing is working. How can i solve this. How can i install all these or any other software.

ERRORS: unable to locate package mysql-cliet-core-5.5
Could,t find any package by regex 'mysql-cliet-core-5.5'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome To The World Of Linux

First of all, Please try to reinstall your os to the latest versionif possible as there are plenty of patches updated. This may be the cause to your problem.

Next, update the current os with all the packages.

Media/ Codecs

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

After following the above steps, try following the steps for MySQL installation
May be that the version is outdated or not supported anymore( Just a thought)